# Modified Twig in PHPStorm

Tags: twig, phpstorm

I have modified my Twig Template Engine to use different brackets.

From:

```
{% if a < b %}

{% endif %}
```

To:

```
{ if a < b }

{ endif }
```

How do I change PHPStorm to recognize this syntax and auto complete?

Comment: AFAIK it's not implemented for Twig templates (Standard Twig Support plugin). Maybe Symfony2 plugin can offer such functionality...

Comment: Hmmm, what about adding additional variables: `{% include 'name.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}`?

Comment: @mwl How would that help me? Problem isn't with the Twig syntax, it is with PHPStorm recognizing the modified syntax and autocompleting "{" with "}".